# How to use SDKMAN! to install packages from within scripts

Tags: bash, sdk, sh, sdkman

Having SDKMAN! installed (http://sdkman.io/), I can install packages from the command line using for example:

```
sdk install java 8u144-zulu
```

However, when I try to do the same thing from within a script "my-installer.sh", I get error message: *"sdk: command not found".*

**my-installer.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sdk install java 8u144-zulu
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to add full path to sdk command.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you need to source in ~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh, like in

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/alexw/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
sdk install java 8u144-zulu
```

'sdk' is a bash function declared in sdkman-init.sh, and your first line (#!...) starts a new(!) shell.

hope that helps! weHe

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to source `sdkman-init.sh` more generically:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

This is similar to the code that SDKMAN adds to your `.zshrc` file:

```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/powers/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/powers/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/powers/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Type `which sdk` if you'd like to see the function that's being sourced:

```
sdk () {
    COMMAND="$1"
    QUALIFIER="$2"
    case "$COMMAND" in
        (l) COMMAND="list"  ;;
        (ls) COMMAND="list"  ;;
        (v) COMMAND="version"  ;;
        (u) COMMAND="use"  ;;
...
...
```