# How to use local jdk in SDKMAN! script

Tags: bash, sdk, sh, sdkman

My script changes to a jdk installed with sdkman but not to a local one. How can I change into my local oracle 8 v261 jdk in a script with sdkman?

The script

```
#!/bin/bash
. /usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
sdk ls java
for i in {"8_261-oracle", "9.0.4-open"}
do
  sdk u java $i
done
```

gives as output

```
[...]
               |     | 9.0.4        | open    | installed  | 9.0.4-open
               | >>> | 8.0.265      | open    | installed  | 8.0.265-open
               |     | 8.0.232      | open    | local only | 8.0.232-open
[...]
 Unclassified  |     | 8_261        | none    | local only | 8_261-oracle
================================================================================
Use the Identifier for installation:

    $ sdk install java 11.0.3.hs-adpt
================================================================================

Stop! java 8_261-oracle, is not installed.

Using java version 9.0.4-open in this shell.
```

I was inspired by [How to use SDKMAN! to install packages from within scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262511/how-to-use-sdkman-to-install-packages-from-within-scripts).

Comment: Bash bracket expression expands into a list here, so it is not needed. `for i in {"8_261-oracle", "9.0.4-open"}`, directly use `for i in '8_261-oracle' '9.0.4-open'` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the output of sdkman to retrieve the list of installed sdks as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sdks=`sdk list java | grep installed | awk -F"|" '{print $6}'`

for sdk in ${sdks[@]}; do
  sdk use java $sdk
  ### YOUR CODE HERE
done
```

I have omitted the `. /usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh` part because I suggest to set it up in bashrc/zshrc as suggested in sdkman doc.

An example from my `~/.zshrc`:

```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$YOUR_PATH/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$YOUR_PATH/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$YOUR_PATH/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```